# How can I register a conjob in Shopware 6 App?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I would like to register "cronjob" to process data for each Shop using my app. Is there a way to register a "scheduled task" in Shopware 6 app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not possible right now, answer detail: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/discussions/3418